# Let $P$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix whose determinant is $10$. The determinant of the matrix $-3P$ is?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $P$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix whose determinant is $10$. The determinant of the matrix $-3P$ is?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\det(-3P) = \det(-3I P) = \det(-3I) \det(P) =(-3)^4 \cdot 10 = 810
$$

Answer (score 2):

Check out some of the determinant properties [here](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~fusaro/EngMath/Ch6/SPDR.html).

They tell you that for an $n \times n$ matrix, $A$, and $c$ a scalar,

$$ \det(cA) = c^n \det(A).$$

Therefore $\det(-3P) = (-3)^4(10) = 810$.